# Cocoapods deployment target issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods to update Google maps to updated version 2.5.0. Using pod  ‘GoogleMaps’, '~> 2.5.0’ in pod file, but when i install it gives me the mentioned error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dependency of the google maps library by two of your other libraries. Those are **Google Places**, **Google Maps/Maps**. That's why it's not able to update it. Update all libraries related to google maps will solve your problem.

Use `pod update` to update all libraries

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: yes definitely it worked after updated version's of both Google Maps & Places.

Comment: Please accept answer so that anyone who faces the same problem can try this solution